# Find a word with a for loop - python

Tags: python, loops, parsing, rss, feed

What I'm trying to do is have python go over all the RSS feed titles and make the terminal print out only the titles with a certain word.

```
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_technology.rss')

print d['feed']['title']
print 'number of entries:  '
print len(d['entries'])
for post in d.entries:
    print post.title + ": "
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [in](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) operator. Additionally, could you be more specific of what you're trying to do? It's unclear.

Comment: It's difficult to be too much help without some guidance on what errors you're seeing, where, and maybe some info on what `type` `d` is (looks like a nested dictionary at first).

Comment: Hi Adam, what exactly is the problem? What is the a word? I don't see it mentioned in your code?

Comment: Ok, what I'm trying to do is have python go over all the RSS feed titles and make the terminal print out only the titles with a certain word.

Comment: I would have an `if hasattr(post, "title"):` in the for loop, for one

Comment: @Andrew what does hasattr mean?

Comment: `hasattr` is a python builtin that checks where the object has an attribute with the name specified, it'll stop your for loop breaking

Comment: Ok, thank you very much... I'll edit it in the code and check back with you!

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems great.
What you are missing is an "if" which check if a specific word exists in the post.title

I've used "if" and "in" to filter only the relevant lines.

Details about "in" can be found here: http://www.jworks.nl/2013/11/07/python-goodness-the-in-keyword/

```
myword = "NASA" 

for post in d.entries:
  if myword in post.title:
    print post.title
```

Comment: בשמחה , אם התשובה ענתה על השאלה, אשמח אם תאשר אותה

Comment: אני אבדוק עם היא עובדת ויחזור אלייך

Comment: בשמחה, בהצלחה בהמשך :)